# Wifi apparently connected, but webpages won't load

Tags: 14.04, wireless, signal

I'm running the latest Ubuntu 14.04.3, and my issue today is that my Wifi connection sometimes becomes really slow, and eventually disconnects. I tried googling around to see if I can get any good answers, but nothing fixed my issue. I found a thread that used a diagnostic tool (wireless-info on github), which might help you guys figure out if there's anything wrong with my current system/drivers. This is what the diagnostic tool found. http://paste.ubuntu.com/12041942/
Is there anything I can do about this? I'd love to get this issue fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no less than *eleven* SSIDs in range with the same name. In your message log, we see your wireless device roaming from among them.

I suggest you ask your wireless to bind to your access point. Right-click the Network Manager icon, select Edit Connections. Fill in the MAC address for your access point; find it with:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

For example:

```
Cell 05 - Address: 00:13:19:F2:2E:D0
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=66/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"UCInet Mobile Access"
```

Use the address (MAC address) you found for the strongest access point to place in BSSID in Network Manager:

[image]

Save and close.

Answer (score -1):

You could maybe try this from the terminal:

```
   rfkill list up
   lspci wlan0
   rfkill list up
```

and then this:

```
   sudo -i
   gedit /etc/networkmanager/ifupdown/ifupdown.conf
```

and then write in this line at the bottom:

```
wirde properties=true
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Do you just type random commands? They will do no harm except creating a useless file in `/etc`. And will do no good.